# Why won't for loop terminate?

Tags: c, infinite-loop, post-increment

My function:

```
int checkSE(disk board[][SIZE], disk hypotheticalDisk)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int row;
    int col;
    int player;
    int opponent;
    int checkSEflag;

    player = hypotheticalDisk.type;
    (player == 0) ? (opponent = 1) : (opponent = 0);

    row = hypotheticalDisk.pos.row;
    col = hypotheticalDisk.pos.col;

    checkSEflag = 0;

    for (i = row + 2, j = col + 2; ((i < SIZE) && (j < SIZE) && (checkSEflag == 0)); i++, j++)
    {
        if (board[i][j].type == player)
        {
            for (--i, --j; board[i][j].type == opponent; i--, j--)
            {
                if (i == row && j == col)
                {
                    checkSEflag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\n%d and %d and %d", i, j, checkSEflag);

    }
    return checkSEflag;
}
```

My output:

> 2 and 3 and 0
>
> 2 and 3 and 0
>
> 2 and 3 and 0
>
> 2 and 3 and 0
>
> 2 and 3 and 0

.
.
.

And it keeps on going...

I want both i and j to increase until they are equal to SIZE (SIZE predefined to be 8) or until checkSEflag is assigned to be equal to 1.

It looks like the values of i and j just aren't being changed...
I tried taking them out of the loop conditions and instead placed them
in the loop body, though that didn't change anything.

I doubt the post increment operators just decided to not work so I must be doing something wrong, any ideas of what that may be?

Comment: `(player==0)?(opponent=1):(opponent=0);` - WTF - Use an if statement to make it readable

Comment: LOL everyone seems to hate the ?: operator

Comment: I do not hate the `?` operator. It has its place

Comment: `opponent = (player==0)` does the same thing and is readable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I concur with you, my learned friend

Comment: Jean-François Fabre coooool! I will add this to my arsenal .. okay point taken, limit the ternary conditionals

Comment: terrible loop's. Even old programmer cant be sure, such code is ok. DO NOT over-hacking. Wite code You will be sure and easy to debug

Comment: Im not trying too, just kind of happens ... So you think maybe instead I should have separted the outermost for loop into 2 (one for i and one for j ) and a while loop (for the checkSEflag)?

Answer (score 2):

These two lines:

```
for(i = row+2, j = col+2; ((i < SIZE) && (j <SIZE) && (checkSEflag == 0)); i++, j++)
    ...
    for(--i, --j; board[i][j].type == opponent; i--, j--)
```

so, you are both incrementing and decrementing (i,j); try sprinkling printfs around these and see if you are both incrementing and decrementing i,j on each iteration...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt even enter the second if statement, so the outermost for loop keeps iterating without even entering the if statement body :///

Comment: Are you sure?  I just run it, using a board of all zeros, and a hypothetical.type == 0, and it hung immediately, because it got into that if, which backed up i,j.   It never executed the inner for loop, but the initialization statement of that for loop did execute.   If you are sure, can you post your “board”;  I’m not really keen on the 2^71 combinations...